# Explicit construction of a model of a fragment of ZF that is not well-founded

Tags: set-theory

From other sources I've seen that there are ways of solving the following question using the compactness or incompleteness theorems, but I am not interested in using those to solve the problem. Any tips would be appreciated.

---

Show  that  there  is  a  model  of  Extensionality,  Foundation,  Separation, Pairing  and Union which is  not well-founded  by  providing  an explicit  definition of a model in which these statements hold.

Answer (score 7):

We can start with a transitive model, say $V_\omega$, and then take an ultrapower with respect to a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega.$ The ultrapower is elementarily equivalent to $V_\omega$ and it is not well founded: for instance $[f_1],[f_2],\ldots$ where $f_i(n) = \max(n-i,0)$ is an infinite descreasing sequence of natural numbers in the ultrapower.